# scroll not working for ipad responsive while checking in desktop

Tags: css

I can't scroll on iPad responsive while checking in desktop. But it is scrolling in iPad.

I have tried by giving overflow commands also but no use.
iPad - cannot scroll inside frame & I also tried this body `{ overflow-y: scroll;}`[image]

Comment: Please post more related CSS codes, especially the lines with effective media queries.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator viewport seems taller (1024px in total) than the browser  window. Please try to resize it or change the zoom % (in the image it is 100%).

Comment: thanks for your comment., when i change the zoom % to 25 or 50 scrolling working fine, but problem is at 100% only.(scrolling not working only at 100%)